# Swagger UI authorization not sending the token

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm new to Swagger. I'm using OpenAPI 3.0.2.

When I run Swagger UI, Authorization buttons appear, both on top and for each API but they don't work. When I click them, I can enter any text in the apiKey box, it accepts it and says that I'm authorized. But no API works, they all return 401

Here is the relevant code in Startup.ConfigureServices

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(
        x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }
    )
    .AddJwtBearer(
        x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
            };
        }
    );
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
            "LibraryOpenApiSpecification",
            new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "Library API",
                Version = "2.0",
                Description = "Text",

                Contact = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Email = "me@google.com",
                    Name = "user1",
                    Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com")
                }
            }
        );

        setupAction.AddSecurityDefinition(
            "Bearer",
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."
            }
        );


        setupAction.AddSecurityRequirement(
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                }
            }
        );


        var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlCommentFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);
        setupAction.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentFullPath);
    }
);
```

The code is not mine, was brought in by another developer.
I will provide more code and info if needed

Comment: Try changing `Type` to `Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http` inside `AddSecurityDefinition` method

Comment: Thanks. I just did that but no change

Answer (score 7):

Here's a working example:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ApiPlayground", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition(
            "token",
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = HeaderNames.Authorization
            }
        );
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "token"
                        },
                    },
                    Array.Empty<string>()
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Once you configure it, Swagger UI gives you a button to authenticate

[image: auth popup]

Once you fill enter the token and send a request, it sends it inside `Authorization` header.

[image: request]

Now, the app must parse & validate this token for each request, so you must enable the auth middlewares inside `Startup.Configure` method.

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Then if the token passes the validation, you should be able to access the user with `HttpContext.User` property.

If you're still getting 401 errors, that implies a problem with the token validation, check if you've configured the authorization services in `Startup.Configure` method:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(
    options => options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).Build()
);
```

this will require all request to authenticate unless another authorization policy is set with `[Authorize]` (or `[AllowAnonymous]`) attribute. This will ensure the token is parsed & validated.

Here's an end-to-end API that signs & validates the token.

```cs
internal class HardCodedConfiguration
{
    public static SymmetricSecurityKey SigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "alongrandomstringhere.11b48736983e87c5cff022c462849ca5b7c5e99b76d81e9707fa35e76024cba8"
        )
    );

    public static SigningCredentials SigningCredentials => new SigningCredentials(
        SigningKey,
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
    );
}

[ApiController]
[Route("")]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("token")]
    public ActionResult SignToken()
    {
        var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(
            new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim("name", "abdusco")
                },
                expires:DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                signingCredentials: HardCodedConfiguration.SigningCredentials
            )
        );
        return Ok(token);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AuthorizedEndpoint()
    {
        return Ok(User.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value }).ToList());
    }
}

// inside Startup class
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // swagger configuration
    // ...
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAuthorization(
        options => options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).Build()
    );
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(
            o =>
            {
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = HardCodedConfiguration.SigningKey,
                };
            }
        );
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work
Here are some details:
1) First of all I'm not sure that I was clear in my OP. There are at least 2 problems here. The first problem is that Authorization button accepts any token, even if I have one defined in appsettings.json. 
2) I had to make some changes in your code as I got an error when I ran it. I replaced your SwaggerDoc with mine in OP
3) APIs still don't work. I followed your instruction and changed level to Debug. I will show the Console message in my next comment as this one reached its char limit

Comment: Here is the Console message:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.

Comment: That button doesn't do any validation. It just forwards the token to the API. Regarding the log message, I know what's wrong. I'll update the answer in a sec

Comment: I added your method but still doesn't work.  I got the same Console message. Forgot to tell that I have app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization(); already

Comment: How about `services.AddAuthorization`?

Comment: Yes I added that. Did you make other changes?

Comment: Does the controller/action have any `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: (Yeah, I've added a fallback policy configuration in my answer)

Comment: Yes but I tried with and without it. Same result

Comment: No luck (that was for you suggested code change that I see is now deleted). On a separate note,  I got a warning from stackoverflow that we shd move this discussion to a chat.

Comment: I've created a new api that signs and validates tokens, and it works just fine. See my updated answer for reference.

Comment: I will try your code but I have some problems with it:

1) [AllowAnonymous] works for me without any change but I need [Authorize} to work

2) So far the controller code was not run at all (it checked for authorization before entering the controller) so I'm not sure what will do the code that you put inside the controller.

Comment: I'm using `.FallbackPolicy`, so you don't need to sprinkle `[Authorize]` everywhere. If you try to call `AuthorizedEndpoint` without a token, you'll get a 401 response. If you change `.FallbackPolicy` to `.DefaultPolicy` then you have to add `[Authorize]` attribute to all endpoints that require auth.

Comment: `[AllowAnonymous]` overrides & bypasses all auth, that's why I had to add it there. If I had `.DefaultPolicy`, then `SignToken` endpoint would require no attributes, and all protected endpoints an `[Authorize]`.

Comment: Also have this issue. Verified authorization works from postman. Seems to be a swagger specific issue with not sending the header properly.

Comment: While this works, it does seem oddly complex to achieve, not sure why it doesn't just support it by default...also it *doesn't* work as expected if you include the "Bearer" prefix when entering the token.

Answer (score 2):

To get Swagger UI (.NET 6, OpenApi v3, Swashbuckle v6.5) authentication to work for me, I had to create a `AuthenticationRequirementsOperationFilter` and add it to the filters as mentioned in [this github answer](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1425#issuecomment-571926368). It was also important that the keyword `bearer` was kept the same in `AddSecurityDefinition` and `OpenApiSecurityScheme`.

Here is that sample code:

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
        {
            opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My Api", Version = "v1" });
            opt.AddSecurityDefinition("bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Scheme = "bearer"
            });
            opt.OperationFilter<AuthenticationRequirementsOperationFilter>();
        });
    }
}

public class AuthenticationRequirementsOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Security == null)
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>();

        var scheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "bearer" } };
        operation.Security.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            [scheme] = new List<string>()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. The token generated was not being sent. Perhaps the AuthenticationRequirementsOperationFilter was required since my end points were not explicitly decorated with Authorize attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey then you need to append keyword Bearer with token like 'Bearer ' and the name of token variable should be Authorization only or you can replace the Security Scheme Type with Http then you don't need to declare any variable name and no need to append bearer while passing the token.